# Cakephp email activate

Tags: php, cakephp-2.0

In the `UserController::activate()` I see this

```
$this->User->updateAll(array(
    $this->User->escapeField('status') => $db->value(1),
    $this->User->escapeField('activation_key') => $db->value($key),
), array(
    $this->User->escapeField('id') => $this->User->id 
));
```

What is the purpose of the second last line about the ID?

Answer (score 0):

It's Conditions, for which columns needs to be updated, See [Docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-mixed-conditions)

From Docs

> **`Model::updateAll(array $fields, mixed $conditions)`**
>
> Updates one or more records in a single call. Fields to be updated,
>   along with their values, are identified by the `$fields` array. Records
>   to be updated are identified by the `$conditions` array. If `$conditions`
>   argument is not supplied or it is set to true, all records will be
>   updated.

Answer (score 0):

It says to the database to update the `users` table where `id` equals to `$this->User->id`